# ListAppend() not working?

Tags: list, function, coldfusion, append

I have a problem with my cfml code. The `ListAppend()` function doesn't seem to be working.

Here is the code in my .cfm page:

```
<cfset fruitList="apple, orange, banana">

<cfoutput>
    fruitList before: #fruitList#<br>
</cfoutput>

<cfset temp = ListAppend(fruitList, "kiwi")>
<cfoutput>
    fruitList after: #fruitList#<br>
</cfoutput>
```

But I always get this output:

**fruitList before: apple, orange, banana**

**fruitList after: apple, orange, banana**

The same goes for `ListPrepend()` and `ListInsertAt()`. Why does this happen?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you need to use `<cfset fruitList=ListAppend(fruitList, "kiwi")>`

Comment: When you run into questions about function behavior, it is always good to [check the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6d71.html) first. As it would have answered your question instantly ;): `ListAppend` - "Returns A copy of the list, with [the new] *value* appended"

Comment: Yep, unlike cousins `ArrayAppend()` and `StructAppend()`, `ListAppend()` does not alter the first argument by reference.

Comment: In Mohsin's defense the question shows in Google and helps me to remember I need to assign the return back to the list, vs, as @Mike Causer mentions, ArrayAppend() and StructAppend(). It was a consistency oversight from way back when and I often forget.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

listAppend() returns the new list (lists are nothing but strings, which ColdFusion passes by value) so in order for you to see appended value, you would need to  use:

```
<cfset fruitlist = ListAppend(fruitList, "kiwi") />
```

Comment: I didn't notice that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
<cfset fruitList="apple, orange, banana">

<cfoutput>
fruitList before: #fruitList#<br>
</cfoutput>

<cfset fruitList=ListAppend(fruitList, "kiwi")>

<cfoutput>
fruitList after: #fruitList#<br>
</cfoutput>
```

Accord to cfquickdocs listAppend returns the list with the value appended to it.
http://cfquickdocs.com/#ListAppend

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, in your example, you are appending to a list just fine. You are, however, creating a new list, "temp", and copying the contents of fruitlist to it and then appending kiwi.

```
<cfset temp = ListAppend(fruitList, "kiwi")>
```

If you were to dump the temp list, you'd see the list that you want to see.

```
<cfdump var="#temp#">
```